# Cocoapods erro no such file or directory: 'OpenGLES'

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Quero adicionar a biblioteca GoogleMaps ao meu projeto. Então instalei o cocoapds e segui todos os passos que estão no site da google [siteGoogle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start). Já andei a vaguear por forums e já experimentei várias das soluções apresentadas mas tenho sempre o erro:

"no such file or directory: OpenGLES"

Alguém me consegue ajudar nesta..

Comment: Olá @HideCode, coloque o trecho do código e do `import` que você fez assim podemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Como está seu **podfile** ? Cola aqui.